# How can i get h3 tag text value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I write the following code to generate `<h3>` tags:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.adslList)
{
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">
            <h3>@item.Count</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <h3>@item.Price</h3>
            <button type="button" id="buyBTN"  name=@item.Count class="btn btn-success">خرید</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I want to write some thing in this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buyBTN").click(function () {
        ....
    });
});
```

want to when user click on the `buyBTN` show that `<h3>` `@item.Count` and `@item.Price`. How can i write code for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop is generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes in the `<button>` element. Use a class name instead so you can use relative selectors

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.adslList)
{
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">
            <h3>@item.Count</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <h3>@item.Price</h3>
            <button type="button" class="buyBTN" name=@item.Count class="btn btn-success">خرید</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

$('.buyBTN').click(function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.flip');
    // Get the text in the h3 elements
    var count = container.children('.front').children('h3').text();
    var price = container.children('.back').children('h3').text();
});
```

Alternatively you can store the values in the `<button>` element using `data-*` attributes

```
<button type="button" class="buyBTN" data-count="@item.Count" data-price="@item.Price" name=@item.Count class="btn btn-success">خرید</button>
```

and get them using

```
$('.buyBTN').click(function () {
    var count = $(this).data('count');
    var price = $(this).data('price');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You basically have to access the values of the h3 elements in different divs.You can do so in jQuery easily.

Assuming you implement this functionality in $(document).ready() event ,you need to use something similar to:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    alert($(".front h3").text());
    alert($(".back h3").text());
})
```

Since you want to access the values of the h3 elements inside the button click event:

```
 $("#buyBTN").click(function () {
       var count=$(".front h3").text();
       var price=$(".back h3").text();

    });
```

Comment: That will only return the combined values of the all `<h3>` elements (and who in the world up-voted this) - suggest you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/)